# for any $K \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$, there is always a solution for nature number equation

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

prove that there is always a positive integer $n$ and $a$, such that $(4n-1)a=(K+n)(4K+1)+1$, for any positive integer $K$

It is natural to start with,
$3a=(K+1)(4K+1)+1$,
$7b=(K+2)(4K+1)+1$,
$11c=(K+3)(4K+1)+1$,
....
If any one of the above has a solution for any $K$, then it is solved.

However, for K=1009, there is no solution unfortunately. So the question will be closed.

Background: it relates with erdős–straus conjecture, if the equation has solution, then the conjecture will be solved. I am curious why it failed so I attached the question here.

Comment: What makes you think this is true?

Comment: There is no solution for $K=1$ too. What is the source of the question?

Comment: Please correct the word "nature" in the title.  Did you mean "natural number", $\mathbb{N}$, as in $1, 2, 3, 4, ...$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The probelm is equivalent to showing $(4n-1)|(K+n)(4K+1)+1$:
$$\iff (4n-1)|(4K^2+4Kn+K+n+1)$$
$$\iff (4n-1)|(4K^2+2K+n+1)$$
$$\iff (4n-1)|[4(4K^2+2K+n+1)] \tag{$\gcd(4n-1,4) = 1$}$$
$$\iff (4n-1)|(16K^2+8K+4n+4)$$
$$\iff (4n-1)|(16K^2+8K+5)$$

Thus, the problem boils down to finding whether $16K^2+8K+5$ has a factor (or a prime factor) of the form $(4n-1)$. 
Now, $16(1009)^2+8(1009)+5 = 17\cdot 958669$ and $16(1)^2+8(1)+5 = 29$. So, there is no solution for both $K=1$ and $K=1009$ (and many, possibly infinite, values of $K$).

---

**Edit**: It seems as if there is no $K$ (till 10000) such that the said expression has a factor of the form $4n-1$, which leads me to believe the original question could have been:

> Prove that there are no positive integers $n$ and $a$ such that for any $K \in \Bbb Z^+$, $$(4n-1)a = (K+n)(4K+1)+1$$

---

**Edit**: Proof that there is no solution $(a,n)$ for any $k \in \Bbb Z^+$.: (thanks to the observation made by Gerry Myerson)
Assume an odd prime $p$ divides $16K^2+8K+5 = (4K+1)^2+4$.
$$\implies x^2 \equiv -4 \pmod p$$
Since $p$ is an odd prime, $\exists y$ s.t. $2y \equiv 1 \pmod p \implies 4y^2 \equiv 1 \pmod p$. Multiplying yields:
$$4x^2y^2 \equiv -4\cdot 4y^2 \equiv -4 \pmod p$$
$$\implies (xy)^2 \equiv -1 \pmod p$$i.e., $-1$ is a quadratic residue $\pmod p$, so $p$ is in fact $1 \pmod 4$ or $p$ is of the form $4k+1$. Hence, we are done.

Comment: Can anyone prove that $16K^2+8K+5$ has no factor of the form $4n-1$

Comment: $16K^2+8K+5=(4K+1)^2+2^2\equiv0\pmod p$ says $-4$ is a quadratic residue modulo the prime $p$, which says $p=4n+1$.

Answer (score 0):

conterexample: $K=1009$. there is no solution of $n$.